# I cannot have two (or more) fields with the same name when creating columns in a DataGrid of MUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, datagrid

I am creating a DataGrid where I want to show the values of `ready_by` and `name` that you can see in this picture:

[image: Json of the data]

In the code, I have configured it in this way: (focus on the last two)

```
const columns = [
    {
      field: 'id',
      headerName: "ID",
      minWidth: 50,
      type:"number",
      align:'left',
      hide:'true'
    },
    {
      field: 'customer',
      headerName: 'Customer',
      valueGetter: ({ value }) => value.email,
      width: 250,
    },
    {
      field: 'paid',
      headerName: 'Customer has paid?',
      width: 250,
    },
    {
      field: 'total',
      headerName: 'Cost',
      width: 150,
    },
    {
      field: 'details',
      headerName: 'Ready By',
      type: 'datetime',
      valueGetter: ({ value }) => value.ready_by && new Date(value.ready_by),
      width: 250,
    },
    {
      field: 'details',
      headerName: 'Name',
      valueGetter: ({ value }) => value[0].name,
      width: 250,
    },
  ];
```

The problem is that when I render the page only one of them shows up and that's because I repeat the `field` value. So I want to ask you how to resolve this:

[image: Page with the Datagrid]

Comment: from the docs "field is the only required property since it's the column identifier." i guess you have to change field to be unique. https://mui.com/components/data-grid/columns/

Comment: How can I do that? I don't see the propertie "unique" in the column documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct. The "field" is a column identifier and must be unique.

Here's my solution:

Assumption: Here `data` means the array you're feeding to the `rows` prop for the `<DataGrid/>` MUI component.

```
const columns = React.useMemo(
     () => [
       ..., // all the other elements

  
       // No changes needed here since this is the first occurrence of 'details'
       {
         field: 'details',
         headerName: 'Ready By',
         type: 'datetime',
         valueGetter: ({ value }) => value.ready_by && new Date(value.ready_by),
         width: 250,
       },

        // Here we're basically searching for the item of interest since we do get `id` as a param arg.
       {
         field: 'details2',
         headerName: 'Name',
         valueGetter: ({ id }) => {
           const item = data.find(item => item.id === id);
           return item.name;
         },
         width: 250,
       },

     ],
    [data]
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

The `params` object from a `ValueGetter` contains a `row` property which contains the entire model that the row is mapped from. So you can just assign a unique ID in `field` (doesn't have to match a property on your object), and get the value from `params.row`. E.g.

```
...
// Leave this one the same
{
  field: 'details',
  headerName: 'Ready By',
  type: 'datetime',
  valueGetter: ({ value }) => value.ready_by && new Date(value.ready_by),
  width: 250,
},

// Set a unique field and get the relevant data using the row property
{
  field: 'name',
  headerName: 'Name',
  valueGetter: (params) => params.row.details[0].name,
  width: 250,
},
...
```

This is much more efficient than using `find()` on the whole list of data since we already know the specific model for this row.

The params for a `ValueGetter` are of type `GridValueGetterParams`. There is not much documentation about this type, but according to the source, it extends `GridCellParams`, which contains [some info](https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/grid-cell-params/) about `row`.